# Flatbuffers flatc schema compiler not generating file

Tags: flatbuffers

I'm trying to run `flatc -s test.idl` without success. This used to work but after changing laptops I'm not able to compile the schemas anymore. If I intentionally break the test.idl, I get errors, but with correct syntax it just fails silently.

test.idl looks like this:

```
namespace Foo;
enum Type : byte {
  type_request = 1,
  type_reply = 2,
}

struct UUID {
  low_bytes: ulong;
  high_bytes: ulong;
}

table Request {
  req_id: UUID    ( required );
}
root_type Request;

table Reply {
  req_id: UUID    ( required );
}
root_type Reply;
```

Any ideas? I'm likely running different version of flatc (currently 1.7.0), has something changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it seems (only?) `.fbs` extensions are supported now, so changing the name and running `flatc -s test.fbs` works fine.

Comment: Yes, any other extension it will assume it's JSON or something it doesn't need to generate code for. That's still a bug, it should warn you.

Comment: Was fixed here: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/commit/a6a3f5925393146e879ba03d919a3380b9af7994

Comment: @Aardappel, great and thanks for the fix! If you found out the bug from this Q/A and feel like it was beneficial for you, feel free to upvote.